# Rails Factories association fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, fabrication-gem

I've been fighting with this all day. The problem is the same with Fabrication or FactoryGirl so I guess it has to do with Active Record or Rails.

Let's take the following code:

```ruby
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_order

  # Associations ------------------
  belongs_to :company

  # Validations -------------------
  validates :name, :order, :presence => true
  validates :order, :uniqueness => { :scope => :company, :message => "order should be unique" }

  def set_order
    return unless self.order.nil? || self.order.blank?

    company_categories = self.template && self.company.categories.template || self.company.categories.non_template
    self.order = (company_categories.empty? && 1) || (company_categories.map(&:order).sort.last + 1)
  end
end

# spec/factories/companies.rb
Fabricator :company do
  Fabricate.sequence(:name) { |n| "Company #{n}" }
  creation_date Date.today
  template false
end


# spec/factories/categories.rb
Fabricator :category do
  name ["Business", "Finance", "Analytics"][Random.rand(3)]
  template false
  company
end


# spec/models/category_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Category do
  let(:category) { Fabricate(:category) }

  it "has a valid factory" do
    category.should be_valid
  end

end
```

Every time I run the spec, I get the following error:

```
1) Category has a valid factory
   Failure/Error: let(:category) { Fabricate(:category) }
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
     PG::Error: ERROR:  column categories.company does not exist
     LINE 1: ..."categories"  WHERE ("categories"."order" = 1 AND "categorie...
                                                                  ^
     : SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories"  WHERE ("categories"."order" = 1 AND "categories"."company" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
   # ./spec/models/category_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/models/category_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It looks like the association is not set properly. To sql query is "categories"."company" and not "categories"."company_id". It is super weird.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trying to run the validation on order. Your scope there is `company` which is where it is getting `company` instead of `company_id` from. Try:

```
validates :order, :uniqueness => { :scope => :company_id }
```

Answer (score 0):

db not ready yet. Run

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```